# Cannot get the input type value using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'am trying to get the value of the input type text in the following way:

```
$( document ).on( 'click', '.reset-to-default-img', function(e) {
    alert($('#image').val());
  });
```

When i click the button i got undefined alert message. I want to get the value. Not sure why. Here's my html:

```
  <p>
  <!-- Set Default Custom Image  -->
  <label for="widget-gallery-posts-widget[__i__][image]"></label>
  <input name="widget-gallery-posts-widget[__i__][image]" id="widget-gallery-posts-widget-__i__-image" class="widefat" type="text" size="36"  value="" />
  <button class="upload_image_button button button-primary" type="button">Upload Your Custom Default Image</button> <br /> <br />
          <img src="http://localhost/Gallery-Posts-Widget/wp-content/plugins/gallery-posts-widget/views/images/default-thumbnail.jpg"  id="custom-default-img" width="150" height="100" />
      </p>
```

I want to get the value of this input:

```
  <input name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'image' ); ?>" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'image' ); ?>" class="widefat" type="text" size="36"  value="<?php echo esc_attr( $image ); ?>" />
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: where is your element with `image` id?

Comment: When asking a question about what's happening client-side, show us *what your browser sees*, not the PHP code that generates it. Ideally, provide a **runnable** [mcve] demonstrating the problem, using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). That will help you get good answers more quickly.

Comment: I'am generating the id in this way: id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'image' ); ?>"

Comment: what does this " id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'image' ); ?>" generates?

Comment: So your id is `widget-gallery-posts-widget-__i__-image` not `image`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) method in combination with [find](https://api.jquery.com/find/) method.

```
$( document ).on( 'click', '.reset-to-default-img', function(e) {
  var image=$(this).closest('p').find('.widefat').val();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

From your php method you are getting id `widget-gallery-posts-widget-__i__-image` not `image` so change your code as below

```
$( document ).on( 'click', '.reset-to-default-img', function(e) {
    alert($('#widget-gallery-posts-widget-__i__-image').val());
  });
```